# Where can I find Magic: the Gathering puzzles?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, puzzles

The Duelist used to publish MTG puzzles by Mark Rosewater in which you were placed in the last turn of a game and had to figure out the correct play to win.  I remember these puzzles being extremely fun and a great way to improve skills.  I know that these puzzle were collected in Magic: the Puzzling, but with the M10 rules changes, these might be outdated/broken.  Is there any other place I could find something similar?

Comment: Anything that was in The Duelist has been obsolete since 6th Edition :)

Comment: @Affe: actually the Duelist continued to publish until just prior to the release of Mercadian Masques, which was several months after 6th edition came out. If I remember correctly, the last 7-ish issues had puzzles that used the 6th edition rules and would still mostly work as designed today. Even prior to that, there were probably quite a few puzzles that weren't "broken" by the 6E rules update.

Comment: I remember those days. I submitted my answer to one of them and actually won a nice little package. Got an Unglued t-shirt with Jester Sombrero pictured and 10 unopened booster packs (can't remember what expansion set though). My name was in the next issue as the third prize winner. Ahhhh the good ol days of Magic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Duels of the Planeswalkers 2012](http://www.wizards.com/magic/digital/DuelsOfThePlaneswalkers.aspx) includes several puzzle games.

Gatheringmagic.com has a [pretty nice archive](http://www.gatheringmagic.com/category/puzzles/) of puzzles.

Comment: the other two versions of Duels of the Planeswalkers also have puzzles in

Comment: First link became broken :/ ... not sure if what you linked is now [this link](https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/magic-duels)

Answer (score 2):

ChannelFireball has a category mostly fed by LSV called [What's The Play?](http://www.channelfireball.com/tag/whats-the-play/), which features articles in sets of two, being a puzzle and LSV's respective solution that's realeased a few days later.

The puzzles aren't always win-or-lose situations, but also about what the correct play is to be best off for the rest of the match. The presented situations are mostly from actual game situations taking place, either from LSV himself, or by other players. You can also submit your own predicaments and have them featured on the format.

While LSV is handling the presentation, it's not intended as a "one person knows best" idea, but encourages people to brainstorm in the comments, where you can also see what other people thought was a good play, and why.

Answer (score 2):

Since March 2017, there is a blog-style collection of puzzles called [Possibility Storm](http://www.possibilitystorm.com/).

As of now, the page is continuously updated Mondays, and features everything you need in a single image. All puzzles have a difficulty rating applied to them. Generally, the same blog post will have a solution hidden by default, although some of them are unfortunately only available after donating via Patreon.